Problem about minimizing the expression $\mathbb{E}[(\delta _0(X)/v(Y)-1)^2]$
I want to understand the proof of the Theorem 6.18 which is in the page 351 of the book "Theory of Statistics" written by Mark J. Schervish.
Consider any scenario in which the following objects are well-defined.
Let $X:=(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ be a random variable, $Y=(X_1/|X_n|,\cdots,X_n/|X_n|)$ and $\delta _0(X)$ be a squared-integrable function.
Consider the problem of finding a scale invariant function $v(Y)$ (i.e., $v(cY)=v(Y)$ for all $c>0$) such that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(\delta _0(X)/v(Y)-1)^2|Y]]$ is minimized. That author says that the function which minimizes that expression is given by $v(y)=\frac{\mathbb{E}[\delta _0^2(X)|Y=y]}{\mathbb{E}[\delta _0(X)|Y=y]}$.
My question: how can I prove that assertion?
I don't have any idea about how to prove it, so I didn't make any progress.

You could first minimize the inside conditional expectation: $\mathbb{E}[(\delta_{0}(X)/v(Y)-1)^{2}|Y]=\mathbb{E}[\delta_{0}^{2}(X)|Y]/v^{2}(Y)-2\mathbb{E}[\delta_{0}(X)|Y]/v(Y)+1$. For this simple function $\mathbb{E}[\delta_{0}^{2}(X)|Y]/v^{2}-2\mathbb{E}[\delta_{0}(X)|Y]/v+1$, taking derivative w.r.t. $v$ gives the desired result.
